# Data Entity Framework and LINQ - Get giant data set and execute a command one at a time on each object

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

We are pulling in a giant dataset of records (in the 100's of thousands) and then need to update a field on each one, one at a time in an atomic transation. They records are unrelated to each other and we don't want to do a blind update to all couple hundred thousand (there are views and indexes on this table that make that very prohibitive). The ONLY way that I could get this to work without doing a giant transation was as follows (container is a reference to a custom ObjectContext):

```
var expiredWorkflows = from iw in container.InitiatedWorkflows
where iw.InitiationStatusID != 1 && iw.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Now
select iw.ID;

foreach (int expiredWorkflow in expiredWorkflows)
container.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE dbo.InitiatedWorkflow SET InitiationStatusID = 7 WHERE ID = @ID", new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@ID", Value = expiredWorkflow.ToString() } );
```

We tried looping through each one and just updating the field via the container and then calling SaveChanges(), but that runs everything as one transaction. We tried calling SaveChanges() in the foreach loop, but that threw transaction exceptions. Is there any way to what we are trying to do using the ObjectContext, so it would do something like (the above select would be changed to return the full object, not just the ID):

```
foreach (var expiredWorkflow in expiredWorkflows)
expiredWorkflow.InitiationStatusID = 7

container.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.OneAtATime);
```

Comment: There's no reason you can't loop and save changes each time.  What transaction exceptions are you getting?

Comment: Is there a reason to use EF for this at all? This seems like a thing that can entirely be handled on the database side. You could write a stored procedure and invoke it from your application (you can use EF for this). If you would like to use SaveChanges in foreach loop you can try calling .ToList() or .ToArray() but if you have 100s of thousands of entities you may end up getting OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: if you can turn on MARS in your connect string, that might help get you around needing to finish pulling all the query results.

Comment: do you need to do 1 at a time or just something smaller than 'all at once'?  IOW, could you do them in batches of 500?

Comment: Can you explain why the ExecuteStoreCommand version is 'bad'?

Comment: 100's of thousands? As Pawel said, don't use EF. Don't use an ORM whatsoever. The overhead of creating object kills you. This is sproc work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking generally, if the operation you need to carry out is as simple as the sort of UPDATE your code above suggests, this is the sort of operation that will run far better on the back end database--assuming, of course, there's some clear way to select only the rows that need to be changed. Entity Framework is intended more for manipulating small to medium sets of objects that can easily be loaded into memory and twiddled there, not large bulk-processing operations for which stored procedures are often best. EF can certainly perform those big operations, but it will take a lot longer to execute one SQL statement per row.